# How do I fix this FileNotFoundException (Java)?

Tags: java

How do I fix this error? I've looked everywhere! I usually ask other Runescape Private Server developers to help with this, but no one ever responds to me. This is the error:

```
find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at client.SetNewMaps(client.java:80)
        at client.startUp(client.java:8754)
        at RSApplet.run(RSApplet.java:33)
        at client.run(client.java:6027)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Specdout\Data\Animation\flo.dat (The system 
cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.Fi1eOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Update.unZipFile(Update.java:66)
        at Update.<init>(Update.java:29)
        at client.streamLoaderForName(client.java:4742)
        at client.startUp(client.java:8764)
        at RSApplet.run(RSApplet.java:33)
        at client.run(client.java:6027)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did that caused this error? It will be hard to figure out the solution without knowing what you are trying to do. It looks like you're running some Java code, can you post the code?

Comment: the file is not in the location you defined. That's what the "FileNotFound" Exception says.

Comment: It's suppose to be an autocache downloader, it basically takes the cache for the server and downloads it into the C: for me so I dont manually have to do it myself. I don't have a problem manually doing it, it's just if I try getting other players to play they probably won't have any idea how to do that. Ill try to post the code here but its quite a bit and I'm not even sure that's where the error is coming from. And when I check the cache the files are there so idk why it gives me that error

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the appropriate resource for help with a program you didn't write. If you wrote this code we can help, but if you're a user you're better off contacting the author or the community for the program.

Comment: It's 5 years old and when I got it, it wasn't working properly anyway

Answer (score 2):

When a `FileOutputStream` throws the `FileNotFoundException`, it's because the **directory** doesn't exist.

In your case, that is the `C:\Specdout\Data\Animation` directory. Create the directory, and `FileOutputStream` can create file `flo.dat`.

Note: Could also be security issues.

Comment: @Hosscat Yes. Check the javadoc for the `File` class.